# How a List can be iterated as if it is an array

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have seen code like this:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listOfStrings.add("A");
listOfStrings.add("B");

for(String txt: listOfStrings) {
 System.out.println(txt);
}
```

I have not seen the internal code of ArrayList or its interface, as I don't have the jar need to be attached so as to I can see the source.

Can anyone explain how is this possible?

okay okay. I updated the question.... I want to make it clear like: can I create my own data structure and then through-some-special-internal-code perhaps, user also can use for each loop on my own data structure

Comment: search enhanced for loop in google.

Comment: please reply me also in the regards of updated question. thanks.

Comment: I already get the answer I want to know. Iterable. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create custom functionality for iterating collections ?

Comment: @Veera, no, just want to provide cleaner, easier, non-verbose way of iterating collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works because ArrayList [implements iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Answer (score 2):

This for clause does this:

```
for(T item: Iterable<T>)
```

the first part (`T item`) is for the element that belongs to any class that implements `Iterable` (the second part))

It's actually not an `ArrayList` feature, but you can do it with any `Iterable` class.

Comment: oh. so we need to extend Iterable?

Comment: If you want to create your own Iterable object, yes; ArrayList and many other classes already do it, so you dont' actually have to do extra work. (BTW, you can also use arrays on it)

Comment: yah. your answer is actually satisfy my question also, but I guess I can't mark green more than 1 answer. but thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Because internally it is converted into Iterator for collections.

This for-each loop,

```
for (type var : coll) {
    body-of-loop
}
```

will be converted into following form:

```
for (Iterator<type> iter = coll.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    type var = iter.next();
    body-of-loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for each loop uses an `implicit iterator` over the `iterable` collection. It is more readable and cleaner. As long as you don't want to restructure(remove or swap elements) the collection its a good choice.

Comment: Please explain the down vote, so I can learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

They added this back in Java 5. It's called a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). It's shorthand for looping over the collection with an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

it is a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

another representation of your code is following. it may help you to understand

```
for(int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++) {
 System.out.println(listofStrings.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That [for each loop](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html) converts internally into

```
for(Iterator<String> i = listOfStrings.iterator(); 
                                                  i.hasNext(); ) {
  String txt = i.next();
  System.out.println(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement after compilation
Example:

```
 List<? extends Integer> l = ...
 for (float i : l){
  }
```

is converted to this form after compilation

```
 for (Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
     float #i0 = (Integer)#i.next();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is for each loop ie (enhanced for loop)

```
for(T item: Iterable<T>)
```

internally uses

```
for(int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++) {
 System.out.println(listofStrings.get(i));
}
```

this is best suitable for Collections and Array's(which implement Iterable interface)
the disadvantage is you cannot print in reverse order.